How to Get more then one datasource items data in single GQL query with Sitecore
I want to fetch more then one item data using single GQL query. I am able to fetch the data of single item.
But I want data from two different Items and the both Items has different-different templates. Is this possible single GQL query for Sitecore JSS.
can anyone help me into this? Thanks in advance.
query GQLQuery($datasource: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
  {
   item1
  }
  {
   item2
  }
 }
}


When I will pass this query to Component Graphql Query section then how it will take 2 data source.

I have updated the answer below on how a component GraphQL query, two datasources will be available. Let me know in case you have any queries.

You can pass datasources item path like this "item(path:"/sitecore")"  in your GQL query .

You can do it with multiple ways.
1. If your both items in under same Parent Item then You can assign your parent Item as a data source item. Here is an example: You can easily get multiple items in a single query with filtering out template Id's.
query GQLQuery($datasource: String!) {
  datasource: item(path: $datasource, language: "en") {
    name
    Item1: children(
      includeTemplateIDs: ["{B5D116DE-BFE8-4A06-A3FE-90C84320ECCB}"]
    ) {
      name
      ... on TemplateName {
        title {
          value
        }
        subtitle {
          value
        }
      }
    }
    Item2: children(
      includeTemplateIDs: ["{02CDBE64-254B-424B-90C3-E74FDBA02572}"]
    ) {
      name
      ... on TemplateName {
        title {
          value
        }
        subtitle {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

response:

2. You can easily add extra items to a query. give them a unique name for example:
query GQLQuery($datasource1: String!, $datasource2: String!, $language:String! ){
  item1: item(path:$datasource1, language:$language){   
      id
    }
  item2: item(path:$datasource2, language:$language){   
        title {
          value
        } 
        text {
         value
      }
    }
 }

response:
{
  "data": {
    "item1": {
      "id": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
    },
    "item2": {
      "title": {
        "value": "Sitecore Experience Platform"
      },
      "text": {
        "value": "<p style=\"line-height: 22px;\">From a single connected platform that also integrates with other customer-facing platforms,  to the <a href=\"https://doc.sitecore.net/\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Sitecore Documentation site\">Sitecore Documentation site</a></p>\r"
      }
    }
  }
}

Hope this help!!

Hi Praveen, thank for detailed answer. I have checked both scenarios working for me.

You can combine queries into 1 in GraphQL. Something like this:
query GQLQuery($datasource1: String!, $datasource2: String!) {
  datasource1: item(path: $datasource1, language: "en") {
   {
    item1
   }
  }
  datasource2: item(path: $datasource2, language: "en") {
   {
    item2
   }
  }
}


Although you asked a question about graphql query to fetch multiple item's data and you have received helpful information,
I would suggest to consider using branch templates. It helps to create datasource in a predefined structure.
Ideally, a component should have a single datasource. You can create a datasource like,

Datasource template

Template 1
Template 2



Praveen Sharma has already explained how to fetch data from child items quite well. This will help you to not only create a generic query for your component (to use in Component's Graphql Query section ) but also regulate content authors to follow a hierarchy that you query expects.
Hope this helps.

Yes, it is possible to fetch data from multiple items, even if they are based on different templates, using a single GraphQL query in Sitecore JSS. You can query multiple items by specifying their paths or IDs within the same query.
Here's how you can modify your query to fetch data from two different items in a single request.
query GQLQuery($datasource1Path: String!, $datasource2Path: String!, $language: String!) {
  item1: item(path: $datasource1Path, language: $language) {
    id
    name
    template {
      id
      name
    }
  }
  item2: item(path: $datasource2Path, language: $language) {
    id
    name
    template {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

Here is the response.

Hope this helps.
